# Alignment in textflow

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I'm placing a textflow with UTF-16 text in PHP (PDF_create_textflow,PDF_fit_textflow) which works fine.

How do I get justified Text "" without seeing the BOM sign (Up Arrow) in the Document?

Any other way I could style text justified rather than with inline option *alignment*?

```
$compo_txt = html_entity_decode($compo_txt, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$compo_txt = "<alignment=justify>".$compo_txt;
$compo_txt = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16", $compo_txt);
$len = strlen($compo_txt);
$compo_flow = PDF_create_textflow($p, $compo_txt, "fontname=arial fontsize=".$compo_size." encoding=unicode textlen=" . $len . " embedding=true");


$flow_warning = PDF_fit_textflow(
    $p, $compo_flow, $compo_x + $compo_w, 
    $compo_y, $compo_x, $compo_y - $compo_h,
    'orientate=' . $compo_o
);
```

Comment: please can you share the code snippet?

Comment: sure, hope it helps understanding my problem

Answer (score 1):

Using alignment in optlist not as inline otption did the job:

```
PDF_create_textflow($p, $compo_txt, "fontname=arial fontsize=".$compo_size." encoding=unicode textlen=" . $len . " embedding=true alignment=justify");
```

Answer (score 0):

`alignment` work of course as inline option, but due to the used `textlen` option, this will not work in your case.

Textlen is explained in the PDFlib 9.2.0 API reference with the following words:

> (Integer or keyword; required for text fragments with fixedtextformat=false and textformat=utf16xx in non-Unicode aware languages) **Number of bytes or (in Unicode-capable languages) characters before the next inline option list** (see »Inline option lists for Textflows«, page 103).

(I added the bold highlighting)

As you specify as `textlen` the length of the *complete* textstring, no inline option will be processed.

The main question: Why do you use `textformat=utf16`? Why not just use `textformat=utf8` (or `stringformat=utf8`) if you already have utf8 strings? And you can also use option `charref`, so that character references are processed.

When you set `stringformat=utf8` and `charref=true` (see PDFlib 9.2 Tutorial, chapter "5.2.2 Language Bindings with UTF-8 Support") you can use the simplify your code:

```php
PDF_set_option($p, "stringformat=utf8 charref=true");

$compo_txt = "<alignment=justify>".$compo_txt;
$compo_flow = PDF_create_textflow($p, $compo_txt, "fontname=arial fontsize=".$compo_size." encoding=unicode embedding=true");


$flow_warning = PDF_fit_textflow(
    $p, $compo_flow, $compo_x + $compo_w, 
    $compo_y, $compo_x, $compo_y - $compo_h,
    'orientate=' . $compo_o
);
```